# In App Purchase Restore isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I followed this link to do In app purchase(http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/comment-page-20/#comment-22550). Using Sandbox test User(with US territory) i can purchase the product successfully.i need to restore the product if again i press the Purchase button. how can i know whether the product has already purchased or not? and i need to validate the receipt for auto renewal subscription. how can i do? using objective c.

Comment: Are you using Non-Consumable In App purchase ?

Comment: No, i'm using Auto_renewal Subscription IAP

Answer (score 0):

First, implement a custom payment class conforms protocol `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. This class could be used to receive payment information:

**.h:**

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface PaymentObserver : NSObject<SKPaymentTransactionObserver>
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
@end
```

**.m:**

```
@implementation PaymentObserver

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance{
    static PaymentObserver * instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[PaymentObserver alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
                // Call the appropriate custom method for the transaction state.
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                //Purchased product info goes here. Get more details in transaction object.
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `AppDelegate`, use above class to retrieve payment information:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //......
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[PaymentObserver sharedInstance]];
    //......
}
```

The PaymentObserver class will get the purchased product info from AppStore.

Main procedure is like this. There are more details you are going to handle them.

Comment: Thanks.it's useful. Can you send me full source code or any reference link?

Comment: We made a class just for learning, there is not so many real functions, and the source code file may not be complied when separated from project. Please leave an email if you still want it.